# How can I politely remind ATC that I'm waiting for instructions or clearance?

Tags: air-traffic-control, radio-communications

*(background: low-hour, low-experience, private pilot.)*

I've got an issue regarding talking to air traffic controllers, especially when I think they may have messed up, yet still giving them the respect they deserve as hard working professionals.

One common scenario is when I'm ready to go, along with multiple other planes, all coming from various taxiways.   I know the tower tries hard to clear us each more-or-less in the order we've called up.   But when one plane feels they've been badly skipped, or possibly forgotten, it can get awkward.

I've heard a pilot say (very politely, and with good cause):

> *"Tower; Arrow-23: Did you forget about me?"*

only to have the tower come back with a snappy and frustrated:

> *"I'm doing the best I can.  I'll get you all out of here as fast as I can.  Just wait your turn!"*

Obviously, that didn't go very well.

On the other hand, I've tried to be patient for awhile, only to learn that the Tower really did overlook me, and sequenced several planes out in front of me.

On the ground, its wasted fuel, HOBBS, and time.
But in the air, it can be more significant.

Sometimes I've had tower miss actually clearing me to land.
If they're trying to sequence me in, I stay on an extended the downwind leg for a long time, waiting to be cleared before turning base.  But if they really did get busy and overlook me, I can end up well out of position.

If I call and ask, sometimes they'll get a little testy with me if they are just busy.
If I stay silent, I might've been skipped/forgotten, and end up flying downwind for a long time.

**Whats the most appropriate, friendly, and polite way to check in and make sure nothing got missed, without sounding accusatory?**

Comment: Good question. Many times I have been cleared for the approach and didn't hear anything back (no landing clearance) until I've descended to 200ft. At that time I have other things on my mind than to ask if I was cleared to land or not. On the last occasion I simply went around because they didn't clear me to land. They were really upset (with themselves?) and it never happened again since :-)

Comment: If you need something, just say your callsign. The controller, thinking about other things, will be reminded about you, and if they know what you need they will likely give it to you right then.

Comment: I work at a very slow tower (two or three in the pattern at once is a notable event) so other controllers may have a different perspective, but I don't think it's a requirement for you to have a landing clearance before turning base. Certainly if you don't, you could report turning base to prompt the controller—but I expect pilots to turn a normal base unless I explicitly tell them otherwise (follow traffic, extend downwind, make short approach, etc), whether or not they have a landing clearance at the time.

Answer (score 58, accepted):

There's lots of advice I can give you here, but the answer is really that the degree of communication tower wants/needs depends on your local tower (and to some degree the individual controllers).

Perhaps the most universal piece of advice I can give you is to think like a controller.  Listen to the frequency and get a picture of what's going on in the airspace before you call them, and when you get good at it you'll also get good at knowing what kind of a situation you're flying in to (Is the airspace empty, or are there 4 planes in the pattern for landings, 3 in the opposite downwind shooting touch-and-gos, and a jet arrival on an instrument approach that just got dumped on the tower inside 7 miles barreling in & messing everything up?)

Also remember that from a controller's perspective of priorities ("Safe, Orderly, Expedient") speed doesn't count for much when compared to the other two requirements of the job (and aircraft on the ground are *inherently* Safe and Orderly unless they do something stupid like go charging across the hold-short line). Unfortunately for us pilots delaying the plane on the ground (that isn't moving, and is thus unlikely to hit anything) is generally preferable to trying to maneuver and delay the ones in the air (that can't stop moving unless they hit something, which is generally considered to be a Bad Thing).

For a masters class in "thinking like a controller" call your local tower and ask to arrange a tour / shadow a controller for an afternoon. Spending the day in the cab is a great way to get an appreciation for how crazy things can get up there.
You can usually Google up the phone number, or call Flight Service or your local FSDO and ask. For most towers it's relatively easy to set up a tour (they'll ask for a driver's license and possibly FAA certificate number to do a background check and make sure you're not *completely* insane).

---

The rest of this post is just my personal view on getting along with controllers based on doing most of my training & flying at a pretty busy towered field (According to [the FAA's ATADS "Tower Operations" ranking](http://aspm.faa.gov/opsnet/sys/Tower.asp) KFRG was #42 in 2013).

---

#### On The Ground

When you're ready to go call tower and tell them - Something like `Tower, Cessna 12345 number one runway 32, ready to go.` is usually plenty (if your airport is configured such that there may be some question as to *where* you are specify which taxiway/intersection you're at).

After you call the tower and tell them you're ready my experience is you're not likely to be forgotten about. You may be sitting there for a while (my personal record is about a half hour at the hold-short line), but the tower can *usually* see you sitting there at the runway end waiting. They want to get rid of you, they just need a hole big enough that they can get you onto the runway and airborne without creating any conflicts.

If you *are* forgotten (it does happen sometimes - you'll see other aircraft being cleared for takeoff who called the tower to report ready after you, or the controller changes, or you've been listening and are pretty sure the airspace is clear but you're still waiting) a polite call to remind the tower you're ready to go isn't out of order. Just don't be *That Guy* calling every couple of minutes, and if the controller gets a little snippy just be the better person and shrug it off.

---

#### In The Air

In the air is a slightly different story.  Sometimes it can take me 3 or 4 calls to get tower to even acknowledge my existence on busy days (again, you don't want to be *That Guy* calling the tower every 10 seconds - you should have a picture of what's going on in the airspace, and if the controller is busy you may have to circle outside their airspace for a while).

Once you've made contact a good controller will communicate with you and tell you what they need you to do and where they want you to report, where to turn base, or who they want you to follow.

If you feel like you've been forgotten a well-timed position report is usually the best way to remind the tower you exist (and as a bonus it helps everyone else with their mental picture of the airspace too).
For example on an extended downwind for runway 01 at Republic you'll pass Sunrise Highway (a pretty easily identified road, and if you miss it you'll spot the train tracks right after it), the inner shore of Long Island, and the outer shore of the barrier beaches. Reporting each of those points while waiting for tower to call your base generally works (if they genuinely forgot about you they'll usually have an "Oh S%$^!" moment when you call them over the outer shoreline and turn you in for a 7-mile final).

---

One exception to my position reports technique is landing clearance -- I generally do *something* to remind myself if I've been cleared to land (fold a chart, turn my kneeboard, etc.) and if I don't recall being cleared I'll call somewhere between 500 feet and the threshold with something line `Tower, confirm N12345 landing clearance?` (Where depends on the conditions of the day - sometimes they crank out departures pretty tight & if someone's rolling waiting until they're airborne is usually a good idea).
Sometimes they cleared me and I missed it.
Sometimes they didn't clear me and they do.
Sometimes they have an "Oh S%$^!" moment (they forgot about me, have a conflict, and I go around).

All of those situations are generally preferable to landing on a runway someone else may have been told they can use.

Comment: Excellent advice!

Comment: For landing clearance, what I've been doing is turning on the taxi light when cleared for the approach and the landing light when cleared for the landing.  That way you won't forget if you've been cleared or not, and you can tell right away (and you increase your lighting as you get closer to the airfield, which is always a good idea)

Comment: @Aaron - In most situations, it doesn't hurt to have the landing light on below 10000 ft anyway. It makes you much more visible to any aircraft operating VFR (or in VMC conditions), and it isn't used just for takeoffs and landings.

Comment: I generally just use the taxi light in those situations (since I don't fly IFR), on the premise that you point out, and the taxi instead of the landing light because I would prefer to have the landing light instead of the taxi light if it burns out...

Comment: Awesome answer.  I shadowed a Memphis Center controller for a couple of hours and gained a lot of respect (not that I didn't have any before) for what they do.  I have also been inside Memphis TRACON, and the level of tension is an order of magnitude greater at any given time.  Can't imagine what the Tower is like when 150 FedEx jets are bearing down trying to land in a 45 minute window.

Comment: Great advice. At KPAO common in the local dialect in its busy airspace is “N12345 sequence please”. This way, even if you’ve been told already, they can update you on who is left in the pattern.

Answer (score 27):

What I usually do is repeat the last clearance or instruction. That way you give ATC the impression that you're not impatient but just reporting your progress. If they really forgot you they will quickly rectify the situation. If they didn't and it was intentional, they won't feel as if they are being accused.

**Examples:**

*When holding at a holding point:*

> Tower, N1234, holding RWY 27

*When still on extended downwind, being "forgotten":*

> Tower, N1234, continuing downwind

*When waiting for a landing clearance during approach:*

> Tower, N1234, continuing approach

***And if they still don't clear you when you're already below 200ft or over the threshold:***

> N1234, VERY short final

Comment: I think that your last example is a little too vague.  Sometimes it pays to be specific, such as when faced with an imminent go-around: "Tower, please confirm that N1234 is cleared to land", even if you aren't, tells them exactly what you are looking for and even an "out": "Affirmative,  N1234 cleared to land runway 8".  If they think that they have already cleared you, they may not come back with a landing clearance at that point and you week end up going around.

Comment: I used to do that but I got tired of it because it was happening so frequently so I started saying "very short final", stressing the word "VERY". The last time I simply went around, messing up their sequencing and it never happened again.

Comment: Well, when flying jet airplanes that go-around can cost a whole lot more than I think is worth the satisfaction gained by messing up their sequencing.  :-)

Comment: Getting distracted by a last-second landing clearance can cost even more, and not just in money.

Comment: Hence not waiting until the last second....

Comment: Yes, exactly, and that's why it's so annoying. IMHO, it's unacceptable for a controller to forget about the landing clearance when on short final. It shouldn't be something that the pilot should have to worry about while landing. I get nervous when I haven't been cleared to land (because the controller forgot about it). When I'm nervous I make bad landings, and I think I'm not the only one.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/12271/discussion-between-lnafziger-and-philippe-leybaert)

Answer (score 14):

Lots of good feedback here.  Whenever I am compelled to call the ATC to confirm a clearance or instruction, or if I suspect I was simply forgotten, I just carefully word it as though I may be the one who missed their call even if I'm 99% certain I didn't.

For example, I'd never say, "Tower N1234 sitting at the threshold of 27 ... did you forget about me?"  (Accusative)

Rather, "Tower N1234 sitting at the threshold of 27 ... did I miss your clearance for takeoff by chance?"  (Inquisitive)

Many towered airports ... especially Class Delta ... have their own little methods of madness or traditions or idiosyncrasies that you won't know the first or second time in.  I recently flew in and out of Fort Myers Page Field.  Normally, I'll never switch from ground to tower until told to do so.  I taxied to the runway threshold, did a runup, then called ground to say I was ready to go ... and "Shall I switch to the tower frequency?"

Answer, "N1234, at this airport, whenever you arrive at the threshold you may go ahead and switch to the tower frequency and let 'em know when you're ready."

OK ... fine ... cordial ... polite ... but certainly not by the book.

Comment: I fly in and out of FMY Page quite a bit also. Calling Tower (local) is standard procedure at most facilities in the United States (per the AIM, [4-3-14](https://www.faa.gov/air_traffic/publications/atpubs/aim/aim0403.html)) There are exceptions to the procedure listed below: APA (Centenial Airport in Denver) broadcasts on the ATIS to let Ground Control know when you are ready for departure rather than the tower. This is also done at several large airports with numerous tower frequencies.