# What is the security policy for getting into a Control Tower in the US?

Tags: faa-regulations, air-traffic-control, usa

Are there any regulations the FAA has ruled to get into a Control Tower? Do people need any special kind of security clearance? Are there forbidden items or other special rules?

I'd also want to know if there's a way for non-pilots (your average civilian Joe) to get into a Control Tower.

Comment: Speculating: I read that if you're a licensed pilot, it should be fairly easy to arrange a tour. I'd be interested to know for a private individual though.

Comment: @DannyBeckett http://aviation.stackexchange.com/a/548/327 confirms your sayings

Comment: Ah yes, *that* is where I read it `;)`.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

It is still possible (and in my experience not that difficult) to get FAA tower tours (and sometimes even TRACON or Center tours), though you should be reasonable in your expectations here -- You are probably ***NOT*** going to get a tour of the tower at JFK or LAX.

---

The FAA used to actively encourage pilots with an instrument rating (or pursuing instrument training) to sign up for ATC facility tours under a program called ["Operation Raincheck"](http://www.faa.gov/regulations_policies/orders_notices/index.cfm/go/document.information/documentID/10732) -- This program is still running, though it's been *substantially* scaled back (Poke around on the FAA Safety Team's [SPANS system](https://faasafety.gov/SPANS/events/EventList.aspx), or sign up for notices in your area and keep a sharp eye out. [Tours usually have a ***very*** limited number of slots available, and they fill up fast!](http://faasafety.gov/SPANS/event_details.aspx?eid=52727&caller=/SPANS/events/EventList.aspx)).
(As an example of how quickly the slots fill up, when N90 (New York TRACON) last had a Raincheck event it was full within a few hours of being announced. No, I didn't get a slot.)

---

At towered GA airports - particularly ones with a lot of flight training - you can also contact the tower directly. [The printed AOPA Airport Directory has facility numbers in it](http://flighttraining.aopa.org/flightbag/forms/atc.pdf) but that's a little out of date. You can also get the phone number from Flight Service, the local FSDO, or ask the tower/ground controller for the number if they're not too busy.

When you call the facility explain that you're a pilot/student pilot and would like to arrange to tour the facility (and if possible shadow a controller). They will usually ask for your name, address, airman certificate number, and a few other things to run a check and get approval to let you in to the facility. You will also be expected to have government issued photo ID with you when you show up.

---

My experience arranging a tour of our local tower was extremely pleasant - they are happy to do the tours and let you shadow a controller, and I even got to pick their brains about some peculiarities in local procedures.
It's a great educational experience, and I would recommend it for any pilot/student pilot.

Comment: What about for non-pilots?

Comment: I'm wondering the same, @lnafziger

Comment: @lnafziger That is an excellent question.... that I've got no clue about - I didn't really become interested in what goes on in the tower cab until I had to interact with them :-) Can't hurt to call and ask though.

Comment: @voretaq7 Please do.

Comment: @Lnafziger, when setting up a tour "pilot" or "non-pilot" doesn't really come in to it. You need a photo ID and a pre-arranged appointment and that's about all. Note that non-US citizens should call several weeks in advance because that needs to be approved by people higher up in the FAA; a US citizen visit can theoretically be approved *on the spot* by the non-supervisory "controller in charge" but will more likely be routed to the facility manager for approval.

Answer (score 17):

As @voretaq7 says, getting tours of LAX of JFK towers just won't happen unless you happen to fly for an airline with a base there and/or are good at persuasion.  I've tried to negotiate a tower tour with the supervisor at LAX on short notice but he did indicate if I had a lot of lead time they might have been able to work something out.

The easiest way to get a tour in my experience is just to call and ask for someone to talk to to request a tour.  I've been in the tower cab at EWR, AUS and CRG and in the Austin TRACON.  All of those were arranged with a phone call, a social security number and proof of citizenship (all post 9/11).  It helps to mention you  are a pilot and want to see how things work on their side.

Typically the tower guys are going to want at least one of you to be a pilot and they'll want more lead time if you are bringing a group.  They'll also probably want to verify citizenship for everyone ahead of time and you'll want to be up front if you have an non-US people in the group just so they don't get surprised when you show up and they ask for passports or other ID.  Bring donuts.

I have also toured the San Angelo, TX FSS.  For those guys I was already on field and just called the briefing number and asked if I could walk over.  They were happy to have us (I had a student with me).

If you want a tour of any facility, just call.  They'll tell you what *they* require and how and when the tour will happen and who you can bring.

Comment: +1 for "bring donuts"

Answer (score 5):

I've arranged tours of two control towers (a class D and a class B) and a TRACON without any issues. I was only required to provide proof of US citizenship, from what I remember.

You must turn OFF (not airplane mode) cell phones before entering the tower or active part of the TRACON.