# Where can I get flight departure change data?

Tags: flight-schedules, flight-plans

On sites like flightstats.com, there is an "event timeline" view that shows changes made to the scheduled departure or equipment for a commercial flight. I assume this information is being pulled from some central system / API.

[Here's an example, from today](http://www.flightstats.com/go/FlightStatus/flightStatusByFlightExtendedDetails.do?id=750485822&airlineCode=UA&flightNumber=161)

```
Jul 26  05:00   1:00 AM 6:00 AM Gate Adjustment 
TAIL Changed From N14106 To N14102

Jul 26  14:27   10:27 AM    3:27 PM Gate Adjustment 
Departure Gate Changed From 125 To 128

Jul 26  20:23   4:23 PM 9:23 PM Gate Adjustment 
TAIL Changed From N14102 To N34131

Jul 26  21:30   5:30 PM 10:30 PM    Time Adjustment 
Estimated Gate Arrival Changed From 07/27/16 07:30 AM To 07/27/16 07:31 AM

Jul 26  21:31   5:31 PM 10:31 PM    Time Adjustment 
Estimated Runway Departure Changed To 07/26/16 07:50 PM
Estimated Runway Arrival Changed To 07/27/16 06:54 AM
```

Is there a programmatic source for this data? Perhaps with additional metadata not exposed on flightstats.com? I understand they do have an API themselves, which does not seem suited to hobby uses, so I'm looking for another source. Are these departure changes submitted to FAA/ICAO? Are they airport-local only?

Comment: Welcome to the site! You might want to review [this question](http://aviation.stackexchange.com/q/3052/62) and [this one](http://aviation.stackexchange.com/q/1510/62) to see if they're relevant.

Comment: Thanks, @Pondlife - I did check those, and while I have an additional interest in ADS-B - I have a Raspberry Pi dedicated to just that! - I am wondering if there is a source for specific data regarding flight delays before departure. AC changes, gate changes, departure delays, etc. Thanks for checking in so quickly :)

Comment: @mins Fair enough; is there a preferred procedure for reposting there?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because because it belongs to [travel.stackechange.com](http://travel.stackechange.com)

Comment: Welcome Dustin, you can flag your post (`flag` button) explaining the request to move to Travel.SE, moderators will look at it. Enjoy. EDIT: In addition you may search on [SO](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=flightstats.com).

Comment: @mins Thanks for the tip. I've done just that.

Comment: @mins I agree that it might be borderline for us, but I don't think that this question will have a better fate at travel.se

Comment: @Federico: Yes, I edited my comment to mention SO too, SO seems to be the best choice. I didn't look at the API in depth, but [the answer may be there](https://developer.flightstats.com/api-docs/), and someone on Aviation may want to dig into that too.