# Does the European Aviation Safety Agency (EASA) provide real-time data feeds and is there a delay?

Tags: faa, datasets, easa

According to this [answer](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/a/3061/19643):

> You can't get real-time data from the FAA without an operational need, and organizations which do receive real-time data cannot legally re-distribute this data publicly, except to other organizations approved by the FAA. An operational need pretty much means you have to be a flight dispatcher for an airline or commercial operator, not just have an interest in tracking flights.

Great, now apparently, the data feed is delayed by at least 5 minutes... according to [this answer](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/a/1519/19643).

1. Does the EASA provide data such as that provided by the American
   FAA?
2. If so, is there also a delay on data?

   3. If so, what is the delay?

Thanks!

Comment: EASA does not provide any live (or non live) flight data feed. Neither Eurocontrol. At least AFAIK. Don't take for granted that FAA's responsibilities/capabilities/services have a 1:1 match to EASA's.

Comment: Please note that the linked answer is outdated. Last April the FAA dropped the 5 minute delay from its feed.