# How does a (non-pilot) arrange a tour of an ATC facility?

Tags: air-traffic-control, usa

Although [the question has been asked for pilots](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/615/what-is-the-security-policy-for-getting-into-a-control-tower/619#619), how does a civilian get access to a ATC facility? I regularly listen to Live ATC, and I'm incredibly curious as to what the inner-workings of a tower look like.

Even at that, is there a live video feed of ATCs?

Comment: The question you linked to isn't limited to pilots and it even mentions non-pilots. Is there something specific about access/visits that isn't already answered there? Your question about a live video feed is different, perhaps it should be the main question here.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For tours, call the facility and say you're interested in aviation, and would like a tour, same as pilots. Depending on the facility, business hour tours are preferred, though others will let you come any time they have available staffing to escort you around.

As far as I know, there are no video feed of any ATC facilities.

Comment: How do I get the phone number of Norcal TRACON? And SFO ATC?

Comment: @SargunDhillon: I typed "phone number norcal tracon" into google and found relevant information that may be helpful for you.